# Add one additional column to display the data using Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I have one SQL Procedure which returns me 2 columns as a resultant data. Which is as below.

```
    WITH a 
     AS (SELECT To_char(rj_span_id)               AS SPAN_ID, 
                To_char(rj_maintenance_zone_code) AS MAINT_ZONE_CODE 
         --from NE.MV_SPAN@DB_LINK_NE_VIEWER 
         FROM   app_fttx.span@sat 
         WHERE  Length(rj_span_id) = 21 
                AND ( rj_span_id LIKE ( '%SPN%' ) 
                       OR rj_span_id LIKE ( '%SPQ%' ) 
                       OR rj_span_id LIKE ( '%SPR%' ) 
                       OR rj_span_id LIKE ( '%SPS%' ) ) 
                AND ( rj_span_id LIKE ( '%_BU' ) 
                       OR rj_span_id LIKE ( '%_MP' ) ) 
                AND inventory_status_code = 'IPL' 
                AND rj_maintenance_zone_code = 'INAPAPRR01' 
                --AND (RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID IS NULL OR RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID = 'NA') 
                AND ( rj_intracity_link_id NOT LIKE ( '%\_9%' ) ESCAPE '\'
                       OR rj_intracity_link_id IS NULL ) 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT To_char(rj_intracity_link_id)     AS SPAN_ID, 
                To_char(rj_maintenance_zone_code) AS MAINT_ZONE_CODE 
         -- from NE.MV_SPAN@DB_LINK_NE_VIEWER 
         FROM   app_fttx.span@sat 
         WHERE  Length(rj_intracity_link_id) > 8 
                AND Length(rj_intracity_link_id) < 21 
                AND rj_intracity_link_id LIKE ( '%\_9%' ) ESCAPE '\' 
                AND rj_maintenance_zone_code = 'INAPAPRR01' 
                AND inventory_status_code = 'IPL'), 
     b 
     AS (SELECT To_char(span_id)             AS SPAN_ID, 
                To_char(maintenancezonecode) AS MAINT_ZONE_CODE 
         FROM   tbl_fiber_inv_jobs 
         WHERE  span_type = 'INTERCITY' 
                AND maintenancezonecode = 'INAPAPRR01')SELECT span_id, 
       maint_zone_code 
FROM   a 
MINUS 
SELECT span_id, 
       maint_zone_code 
FROM   b;
```

And its output is as below

[![IMG1][1]][1]

And there is another query which has the data of 1st SP in this table

`select SPAN_ID, INTRACITY_LINK_ID from TBL_FIBER_VALID_TRANS_DATA;`

And below is the output

[![IMG2][2]][2]

So now what I want is, I want to add One column in the first procedure which will check if the relevant `SPANID` is available in the second query.

So if the SPAN ID exist then in the newly created column it should add as `VALID` and if doesn't exist it should add as `INVALID`

**NOTE**

This was my way of getting this things done. IF we can do it in single procedure or any other way then it will be appreciated.

Comment: I think you are looking into outer join (probably LEFT JOIN in your case) with NVL2(val, 'VALID', 'INVALID').

Comment: @micklesh: can u add with some answer. it would be easy to understand

Comment: Ankit Bajpai has just provided the answer which seems to be valid, the only difference from what I proposed is the way to display the VALID/INVALID, instead of CASE.... you can use the NVL2 function as `NVL2(VTD.SPAN_ID, 'VALID', 'INVALID')`

Comment: when you are left joining two tables, if a value is not matched, the column remains NULL, **NVL2** function (not NVL) just allows to display valid/invalid text. CASE statement also could be used as suggested in the answer

Comment: @micklesh: one more thing, I would like to mention here... I tried with `Ankit's` answer, its returning me more than actual row what it was. Earlier it was 73 records and after executing ankits answer it fetched me 435 rows.. why big difference ?

Comment: Well, NVL2 wouldn't change the number of entries, it's just a replacement of the case. On the more records issue - do you have any duplication in the second table?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213273/discussion-between-hud-and-micklesh).

Comment: @micklesh: can u come on chat mate ?

Comment: @micklesh: can u join the same chat, as i am unable to tag u for discussion

Comment: @micklesh: can u come over chat here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217525/querydiscussionfororacle as the earlier link for chat is frozen and we cant their

Comment: @micklesh: can u try from here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217583/room-for-hud-and-micklesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need LEFT JOIN. Try below query -

```
SELECT T.SPAN_ID
      ,MAINT_ZONE_CODE
      ,CASE WHEN VTD.SPAN_ID IS NULL THEN 'INVALID' ELSE 'VALID' END FLAG
FROM (WITH a 
     AS (SELECT To_char(rj_span_id)               AS SPAN_ID, 
                To_char(rj_maintenance_zone_code) AS MAINT_ZONE_CODE 
         --from NE.MV_SPAN@DB_LINK_NE_VIEWER 
         FROM   app_fttx.span@sat 
         WHERE  Length(rj_span_id) = 21 
                AND ( rj_span_id LIKE ( '%SPN%' ) 
                       OR rj_span_id LIKE ( '%SPQ%' ) 
                       OR rj_span_id LIKE ( '%SPR%' ) 
                       OR rj_span_id LIKE ( '%SPS%' ) ) 
                AND ( rj_span_id LIKE ( '%_BU' ) 
                       OR rj_span_id LIKE ( '%_MP' ) ) 
                AND inventory_status_code = 'IPL' 
                AND rj_maintenance_zone_code = 'INAPAPRR01' 
                --AND (RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID IS NULL OR RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID = 'NA') 
                AND ( rj_intracity_link_id NOT LIKE ( '%\_9%' ) ESCAPE '\' 
                       OR rj_intracity_link_id IS NULL ) 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT To_char(rj_intracity_link_id)     AS SPAN_ID, 
                To_char(rj_maintenance_zone_code) AS MAINT_ZONE_CODE 
         -- from NE.MV_SPAN@DB_LINK_NE_VIEWER 
         FROM   app_fttx.span@sat 
         WHERE  Length(rj_intracity_link_id) > 8 
                AND Length(rj_intracity_link_id) < 21 
                AND rj_intracity_link_id LIKE ( '%\_9%' ) ESCAPE '\' 
                AND rj_maintenance_zone_code = 'INAPAPRR01' 
                AND inventory_status_code = 'IPL'), 
     b 
     AS (SELECT To_char(span_id)             AS SPAN_ID, 
                To_char(maintenancezonecode) AS MAINT_ZONE_CODE 
         FROM   tbl_fiber_inv_jobs 
         WHERE  span_type = 'INTERCITY' 
                AND maintenancezonecode = 'INAPAPRR01')SELECT span_id, 
       maint_zone_code 
FROM   a 
MINUS 
SELECT span_id, 
       maint_zone_code 
FROM   b) T
LEFT JOIN TBL_FIBER_VALID_TRANS_DATA VTD ON T.span_id = VTD.span_id;
```

Comment: hey Ankit, thanks for your answer.. let me try and check

Comment: getting error as `ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
00918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"`

Comment: @hud try SELECT T.SPAN_ID in the first line, also on the 3rd line the ELSE option would be `ELSE 'VALID' END` instead of `ELSE VALID END`

Comment: its returning me more than actual row with your answer...prior to your code it was 73 records but now its showing 435 records

Comment: Its not possible. If you were getting 73 rows earlier, it will still return 73 rows.

Comment: its coming.. may be its due to duplicate records in TBL_FIBER_VALID_TRANS_DATA table

Comment: Yes for sure, There are duplicates in TBL_FIBER_VALID_TRANS_DATA. You can use distinct with TBL_FIBER_VALID_TRANS_DATA table.

Comment: Hi Ankit, can u help me this issue, its same issue as u resolved this one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62822041/update-multiple-columns-based-on-percentage-wise-calculation-in-oracle please help