# Update multiple columns based on percentage wise calculation in Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

NOTE: Updating total question with sample data and output.

I need to update some columns by comparing from another table and update the columns percentage wise. So here I go.

first of all , the query to get **CMM approved length** is below with other columns which I need

```
select CIRCLE,regexp_substr(MP,'[^/]+',1,1)MPNAME,regexp_substr(MP,'[^/]+',1,2)MPCODE,
 SPAN_TYPE,SPAN_LINK_ID,NE_LENGTH AS NE_LEN,
 ROUTE_APPROVED_BY_CMM as CMM_APPROVED_LENGTH from 
 TBL_FIBER_INV_CMP_REPORT_MV
 where CMM_APPROVED_DATE IS NOT NULL OR ROUTE_APPROVED_BY_CMM > 0 OR 
 JOB_PROGRESS_FLAG = 1;
```

and the output of above query looks like this below image

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

**Now comes the second part which is calculation of the percentage wise ratio**

CASE 1: If The CMM approved length in above image is 70km and NE length from (NE,UG, AR len from `NE.MV_SPAN@DB_LINK_NE_VIEWER`)comes out to be 100Km then divide `(UG=80Km and AR=20Km)`

Then percentage of bifurcation would be **80% UG_length and 20% AR_length**. So, against 70km of CMM approved kilometer, `TBL_FIBER_INV_SIGN_OFF_SHEET` should update the column as `UG = 56Km` and `AR = 14Km`.
the bifurcation should be updated in below table `TBL_FIBER_INV_SIGN_OFF_SHEET`

and the table sample data looks like below:-

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

CASE 2: IF `CMM approved length` and `NE length` is same. for ex: 70km (UG = 60 Km and AR=10Km)  then in `TBL_FIBER_INV_SIGN_OFF_SHEET` table should update UG = `60Km and AR = 10Km`.

Below are the table description of both the tables.

```html
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UPD_UG_AR_BY_CMM AS 
   BEGIN


    for cur_r in (
    select circle, 
                   regexp_substr(MP,'[^/]+',1,1)MAINTENANCE_ZONE_NAME,
                   regexp_substr(MP,'[^/]+',1,2)MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE,
                   SPAN_TYPE,
                   SPAN_LINK_ID,
                   NE_LENGTH,
                   ROUTE_APPROVED_BY_CMM
                   from TBL_FIBER_INV_CMP_REPORT_MV    
                  where CMM_APPROVED_DATE IS NOT NULL 
                  OR ROUTE_APPROVED_BY_CMM > 0 
                  OR JOB_PROGRESS_FLAG = 1
        )
        
  LOOP

        IF cur_r.ROUTE_APPROVED_BY_CMM >  SELECT ROUND(SUM(NVL(CALCULATED_LENGTH,0)/1000),4) AS NE_LENGTH,
                                           ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY NOT LIKE '%AERIAL%' OR RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY IS  NULL THEN NVL(CALCULATED_LENGTH,0) ELSE 0 END)/1000,4) AS UG_LENGTH
                                           ,ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY LIKE '%AERIAL%' THEN NVL(CALCULATED_LENGTH,0) ELSE 0 END)/1000,4) AS AR_LENGTH
                                           FROM NE.MV_SPAN@DB_LINK_NE_VIEWER
        THEN
        
          BEGIN
              UPDATE TBL_FIBER_INV_SIGN_OFF_SHEET 
              SET  FSA_UG = UG_LENGTH,  --- divide 80% of NE_LENGTH
                   FSA_AERIAL = AR_LENGTH    --- divide 20% of NE_LENGTH
              WHERE CUR_R.SPAN_LINK_ID =  RJ_SPAN_ID
                
          END
        
        

    NULL;
  END UPD_UG_AR_BY_CMM;
```

but iam stuck at calculation of percentage wise ratio.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: You wrote `NE,UG, AR len from NE.MV_SPAN@DB_LINK_NE_VIEWER)`, but I don't see such columns in its' describe. Please remove unnecessary columns from definition and describe or mark required columns

Comment: And please describe relationship between views/tables and their keys. Also it would be much easier to see meta description of calculation formulas using "table.column" as variables

Comment: shouldn't query from `MV_SPAN` contain `group by RJ_SPAN_ID`? Is RJ_SPAN_ID a join key to TBL_FIBER_INV_CMP_REPORT_MV  and TBL_FIBER_INV_SIGN_OFF_SHEET ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, so finally after tons of clarifications, looks like it should be:

**+update: duplicates**

```sql
merge into TBL_FIBER_INV_SIGN_OFF_SHEET DST
using (
   -- Source: original query
   with mv as (
       select * from (
          select
             circle, 
             regexp_substr(MP,'[^/]+',1,1)MAINTENANCE_ZONE_NAME,
             regexp_substr(MP,'[^/]+',1,2)MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE,
             SPAN_TYPE,
             SPAN_LINK_ID,
             NE_LENGTH, -- ? NE_LENGTH - 1
             ROUTE_APPROVED_BY_CMM as CMM_APPROVED_LENGTH,
             row_number()over(partition by SPAN_LINK_ID order by ROUTE_APPROVED_BY_CMM) rn
          from TBL_FIBER_INV_CMP_REPORT_MV    
          where CMM_APPROVED_DATE IS NOT NULL 
             OR ROUTE_APPROVED_BY_CMM > 0 
             OR JOB_PROGRESS_FLAG = 1
       )
       where rn=1
   )
   ,pct as (
       SELECT 
          ROUND(SUM(NVL(CALCULATED_LENGTH,0)/1000),4) AS NE_LENGTH -- ? NE_LENGTH - 2
         ,ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY NOT LIKE '%AERIAL%' 
                         OR RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY IS NULL 
                         THEN NVL(CALCULATED_LENGTH,0) 
                         ELSE 0 
                    END)/1000,4
               ) AS UG_LENGTH
         ,ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY LIKE '%AERIAL%' 
                         THEN NVL(CALCULATED_LENGTH,0) 
                         ELSE 0 
                    END)/1000,4
               ) AS AR_LENGTH
          FROM NE.MV_SPAN@DB_LINK_NE_VIEWER
   )
   select 
      mv.*
     --,cpt.*
     ,case when mv.CMM_APPROVED_LENGTH > pct.NE_LENGTH then 0.8 * pct.UG_length
           when mv.CMM_APPROVED_LENGTH = pct.NE_LENGTH then 0.9 * pct.UG_length
      end as FSA_UG
     ,case when mv.CMM_APPROVED_LENGTH > pct.NE_LENGTH then 0.2 * pct.AR_LENGTH
           when mv.CMM_APPROVED_LENGTH = pct.NE_LENGTH then 0.1 * pct.AR_LENGTH
      end as FSA_AERIAL
   from mv, pct
   -- end of Source query
) SRC
on ( dst.SPAN_LINK_ID =  src.SPAN_LINK_ID )
when matched then update
   set FSA_UG = src.FSA_UG
      ,FSA_AERIAL = src.FSA_AERIAL;
```

Comment: check the query in `pct` - is it really correct? I took it from your question

Comment: check second query

Comment: you can add other columns if you need into the main SELECT

Comment: pct.UG_length / (pct.UG_length + pct.AR_LENGTH) is a "percentage": simple formula A/(A+B), so in case of 80 and 20 it will be 80%: 80/(80+20)

Comment: are  80% & 20% static percentage? not dynamic?

Comment: I've just updated answer: check it please. If it returns correct data, I can easily modify it to update statement

Comment: sorry I have no time. Create new topic and describe you requirements with all schemas, data, relationships, formulas, sources, etc *fully and properly* and probably somebody will help you. You current desciption is absolutely uncertain

Comment: Thanks buddy for your support. made few more changes and got it cracked..!!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question explanation the update  should be

```
update TBL_FIBER_INV_CMP_REPORT_MV 
set UG =  CASE WHEN ROUTE_APPROVED_BY_CMM > 70 AND  NE_LENGTH >= 100 
        THEN NE_LENGTH*0.8 
      WHEN ROUTE_APPROVED_BY_CMM =  NE_LENGTH 
    THEN NE_LENGTH*(60/70)  
    ELSE 0 END

 , AR = CASE WHEN ROUTE_APPROVED_BY_CMM > 70 AND  NE_LENGTH >= 100 
        THEN NE_LENGTH*0.2 
      WHEN ROUTE_APPROVED_BY_CMM =  NE_LENGTH 
    THEN NE_LENGTH*(60/10) 
    ELSE 0 END
```