# Getting duplicate dates while repeating the rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to rotate or repeat the sfhitId(1,2) between the date range for each employee.

Everything is working fine but I don't know how to stop getting duplicate dates means why I am getting dublicate dates and how can I rid from it...

Can anyone help me with this?

My only requirement is if any employeeid has 1 or more than 1 shift then shiftId should repeat between given date range for each employee.

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE (EmployeeId int, ShiftId int)

INSERT INTO @TempTable
    SELECT 1 , 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 3 

DECLARE @StartDate datetime = '2020-03-05',
        @EndDate   datetime = '2020-03-09';

WITH theDates AS
(
    SELECT @StartDate AS theDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, theDate) 
    FROM theDates
    WHERE DATEADD(DAY, 1, theDate) <= @EndDate
)
SELECT theDate, EmployeeID, SHiftId  
FROM theDates
CROSS APPLY @TempTable
ORDER BY EmployeeId, theDate
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

[image]

and I want result like this...

```
theDate    EmployeeID   SHiftId
2020-03-05    1          1
2020-03-06    1          3
2020-03-07    1          1
2020-03-08    1          3
2020-03-09    1          1

2020-03-05    2          3
2020-03-06    2          3
2020-03-07    2          3
2020-03-08    2          3
2020-03-09    2          3
```

Comment: Your first table has 3 records, the second table has 5 records, the result is (3*5=)15 records.

Comment: Your query works fine.  What results do you want?

Comment: For each employee Date should not repeate but ShiftId should repeate Between the date range

Comment: I think we're having trouble imagining what the output is meant to look like. Perhaps you could type out the first 3 or 4 rows, demonstrating what you want the output to be.

Comment: Brother I don't know why its not clear :(... It's clearly mentioned that date should not repeat for each employee.... Like 5 to 9 is repeating for employeeID(1)... And my requirement is date should not repeat...

Comment: And ShiftID should repeat as you can see screen shot...

Comment: I have also updated the question...

Comment: Yes, but what do you imagine it would look like without the date repeating? Do you just mean you want the value to be blank in that "cell" or something? That's a presentation layer issue. Or do you mean the whole row should disappear?

Comment: Update the question with expected result..... hope it will be clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions to join the 2 tables:

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE (EmployeeId int, ShiftId int)

INSERT INTO @TempTable
    SELECT 1 , 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 3 

DECLARE @StartDate datetime = '2020-03-05',
        @EndDate   datetime = '2020-03-09';

WITH 
  theDates AS (
    SELECT 1 rn, @StartDate AS theDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT rn + 1, DATEADD(DAY, 1, theDate) 
    FROM theDates
    WHERE DATEADD(DAY, 1, theDate) <= @EndDate
  ),
  theShifts AS (
    SELECT *, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeId ORDER BY ShiftId) rn,
      COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeId) counter
    FROM @TempTable
  )
SELECT d.theDate, s.EmployeeID, s.ShiftId  
FROM theDates d INNER JOIN theShifts s
ON s.rn % s.counter = d.rn % s.counter
ORDER BY s.EmployeeId, d.theDate
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3ed102a43e384236484b44bed12fc143).
Results:

```
> theDate                 | EmployeeID | ShiftId
> :---------------------- | ---------: | ------:
> 2020-03-05 00:00:00.000 |          1 |       1
> 2020-03-06 00:00:00.000 |          1 |       3
> 2020-03-07 00:00:00.000 |          1 |       1
> 2020-03-08 00:00:00.000 |          1 |       3
> 2020-03-09 00:00:00.000 |          1 |       1
> 2020-03-05 00:00:00.000 |          2 |       3
> 2020-03-06 00:00:00.000 |          2 |       3
> 2020-03-07 00:00:00.000 |          2 |       3
> 2020-03-08 00:00:00.000 |          2 |       3
> 2020-03-09 00:00:00.000 |          2 |       3
```

Comment: How window function does work .... Can you please help me to understand how it works... So that I can solve all my queries like this by own :)

Comment: This is the official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 In your case you needed to match the 1st date to the 1st shift, the 2nd date to the 2nd shift etc. This can only be done by assigning the number 1 to the 1st shift, 2 to the 2nd shift etc with the window function ROW_NUMBER(). I also added another column `rn` in `theDates`. So these 2 numbers from the 2 ctes `theShifts` and `theDates` would match under the condition: `s.rn % s.counter = d.rn % s.counter`.

Comment: Is that possible to remove the dates or skip the dates based on some value of each employee... And ShiftId should rotate.. in my case each employee having weekoff days and it could be any days like (sat,sun) or (wed,Fri)

Comment: hi can u help me with this question.. please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62822041/update-multiple-columns-based-on-percentage-wise-calculation-in-oracle